# Rank of Vandermond form of four matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider four matrices A, B, C, D, all with size $2n \times n$. Combining any two of them will get a full rank matrix. For example, [A B] (2n * 2n) is full rank.

Could we say the following matrix (4n*4n)

$\begin{bmatrix}
A&B&C&D\\
A&2B&3C&4D
\end{bmatrix}$
always has a full rank?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a counterexample:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}4 & 1 & 0 & 1\\1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\4 & 2 & 0 & 4\\1 & 0 & 3 & 4\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1\\-6\\-3\\2\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Comment: Wow awesome. I am curious how you find this counterexample. If we add one more condition "all entries in A B C D are 0 or 1", do you think it will make this statement be true?

Comment: How could you have then that each 2-combi is full rank (especially when $n=1$)?